# Why doesn't Where-Object -Match accept args[1] as the regular expression in PowerShell?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, powershell

I created a PoweShell script to update the `<TreatWarningAsError>` value in Visual Studio project files.

```xml
<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Unicode Release|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
        ...
      <TreatWarningAsError>true</TreatWarningAsError>
    </ClCompile>
    ...
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

Its 1st argument is the project file, and 2nd argument is the `$(Configuration)|$(Platform)` string which allows the user to choose one `$(Configuration)|$(Platform)` case to update each time.

```
# usage
# update_vcxproj_turn_off_treat_warnings_as_errors.ps1 notepadPlus.vcxproj "Release\|Win32"

$arg1 = $args[1]
$file = Get-Item $args[0]
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $file)
# $idg = $xml.Project.ItemDefinitionGroup | Where-Object {$_.Condition -Match $args[1]}
$idg = $xml.Project.ItemDefinitionGroup | Where-Object {$_.Condition -Match $arg1}
$idg
$idg.ClCompile.TreatWarningAsError = "false"
$xml.Save($file.Fullname)
```

When passing `$args[1]` to a custom variable `$arg1`, then using `$arg1` after `-Match`, the script gives the correct output.

```
REM Command run in regular CMD
> PowerShell R:\update_vcxproj_turn_off_treat_warnings_as_errors.ps1 R:\npp_2020-08-11\notepadPlus.vcxproj "Release\`|Win32"

Condition      : '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Unicode Release|Win32'
ClCompile      : ClCompile
Link           : Link
Manifest       : Manifest
PostBuildEvent : PostBuildEvent
```

However when using `$args[1]` directly (running the commented line), the script output is not expected.

```
Condition      : '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Unicode Debug|Win32'
ClCompile      : ClCompile
Link           : Link
Manifest       : Manifest
PostBuildEvent : PostBuildEvent

Condition      : '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Unicode Debug|x64'
ClCompile      : ClCompile
Link           : Link
Manifest       : Manifest
PostBuildEvent : PostBuildEvent

Condition      : '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Unicode Release|Win32'
ClCompile      : ClCompile
Link           : Link
Manifest       : Manifest
PostBuildEvent : PostBuildEvent

Condition      : '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Unicode Release|x64'
ClCompile      : ClCompile
Link           : Link
Manifest       : Manifest
PostBuildEvent : PostBuildEvent
```

It should have nothing to do with string interpolation because using `-Match "$($args[1])"` gets the same output as using `-Match $args[1]`.

Tested on both PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell 7.0 on Windows 10 64-bit.

How did that happen? Any clue is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Match interprets the brackets as wildcards.

https://www.educba.com/powershell-wildcards/